# Netezza , Create table with more than 4 organizing keys

Tags: netezza

I need to know if i can create a table with more than 4 organizing keys in Netezza.
I understand CBTs only allow upto 4 organizing keys but my client has a huge table with enormous data and they wanted to have multiple access points for fast data retrieval so it was suggested we use 8 organizing keys to help query the table faster.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you .

Comment: Adding this many organizing keys is less than ideal, have you considered using a materialized view?  I recommend reading this post.
[www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/Netezza/entry/zone_maps_and_data_power20?lang=en]

Comment: MV's and derived tables (drop & recreate a table with a subset of columns) are your friend here. If you really wanted to you could combine columns when you load the table and organize on the combined fields but this is really a bad idea....